# "range between numbers" code [HTML, PHP, SQL]

Tags: php, html

I have been trying for hours to make two textboxes sort the prices from 0 to 999.. I tried google but most of them are not working.. just keep giving my the no data found for range between textbox 1 and 2

I have connected all database and all sort by methods work expect price range (From - to )

The following is what I have done for the Price range,

```html
<form  class="form-wrapper" action="Products.php" method="get" align="right"><div style="margin:0;padding:0">
 <input type="number" id="pricefrom" placeholder="0" pattern="[0-9]" min="0" max="99" size="2" maxlength="2" required name="pricefrom"/>
 <input type="number" id="priceto" placeholder="999" pattern="[0-9]" min="0" max="999" size="3" maxlength="3" required name="priceto"/>  
 <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit"/>
 </form> 
  <?php 

 if((isset($_GET['pricefrom'])) && (isset($_GET['priceto'])))
 {
 $sql="SELECT * FROM  products WHERE Price BETWEEN '%".$_GET['pricefrom']."%' AND '%".$_GET['priceto']."%' ORDER BY Price ASC" ;
 }
 else 
 {
 $sql="SELECT * FROM  products";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo the query and execute it in phpmyadmin to see if it works there?

Comment: Y using string for price?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation about the MySQL subcommand `BETWEEN`? Sheeesh... By the way, good luck with prices like `'0;DELETE FROM products;`

Comment: Also read about SQL injections, you code is vulnerable to them

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
"SELECT * FROM  products 
WHERE Price BETWEEN '".$_GET['pricefrom']."' AND '".$_GET['priceto']."' 
ORDER BY Price ASC"
```

No need of `%`s for `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `%` for BETWEEN.

```
"SELECT * FROM  products
 WHERE Price 
BETWEEN ".$_GET['pricefrom']." AND ".$_GET['priceto']." ORDER BY Price ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
if(isset($_GET['pricefrom']) && isset($_GET['priceto'])) {
    $sql="SELECT * 
          FROM products 
          WHERE Price BETWEEN ".$_GET['pricefrom']." AND ".$_GET['priceto']." 
          ORDER BY Price ASC";
}
```

Also you must take care of [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM  products WHERE Price BETWEEN ".$_GET['pricefrom']." AND .$_GET['priceto']." ORDER BY Price ASC"
```

is the SQL query but after that you have to run the loop to show result...

This will get just the information. after that we have to write:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo ;  // PHP code goes here [1]
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

[1] Here you have to write the code which mention how to display data.